# Listening for new files Python

Tags: python, file, directory, os.walk

I am trying to find a solution to a problem that I have...
I have a big share that contains hundreds of thousands(if not millions) of files and new files arriving every second.
I am trying to write an application that will make it faster to find files in the share my idea was to insert all the file names in to Redis DB in the format of :
`{'file_name','file_path'}` and than when a file is needed to pull its path from the DB...
The problem starts when I am trying to index all the old files(I assume it will take at least a few hours) while simeltaniously listen to new files that arrive during the process.
This is an example of what I'am trying to do:

```
import redis
import os
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost',port=6379,db=0)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'D:\\'):
    for file in files:
        r.set(os.path.basename(file),os.path.join(root, file))
        print 'The file %s was succefuly added' %os.path.basename(file)
```

how am i supposed to modify the code that i will keep listening for new files?

thanks for your help!=)

Comment: What platform are you on? Looks like windows.

Comment: Yup , iam running the code on windows.the share is a NAS.

Comment: Why don't you run a service-like script in the background which keeps running afterwards. It checks for new arriving files. And the initial indexing you could handle by another script (like the one you already wrote).

Comment: BTW, if you don't really need to stick with Python 2, try Python 3.5. It [optimizes os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-471-os-scandir-function-a-better-and-faster-directory-iterator) by a great deal.

Comment: You need a technology for detecting file system events in real time such as is used by antivirus scanners and disk encryptors. An example of that is wrapfs for Linux (http://wrapfs.filesystems.org/). Plus you need an API for using it for which PyFilesystem may do (http://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/introduction.html) and it has a wrapping module for adding functionality to a file system object (http://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/wrapfs/base.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) library. It does exactly what you're looking for. Here's an example of using it:

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```